# Does RunDeck have multi-level job options?

Tags: jenkins, rundeck

Does RunDeck have functionality available analogous to the Jenkins Extended Choice parameter, eg, where secondary/tertiary/etc options are available?

For example, the first level of options would be Pie,Cake,Ice Cream.  If they select "Pie" they get a secondary choice of *Apple* or *Pumpkin*; if they select Cake they get a secondary option of *Chocolate* or *Carrot*; if they select "Ice Cream" they get a secondary option of *Rocky Road* or *Mint Chip*.

I've been poking around on google and the RunDeck UI and don't see anything that even hints at this capability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Rundeck you have the cascade Remote Options that work as you says, take a look at [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/job-options.html#cascading-remote-options). It's based on JSON files and [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rundeck-discuss/CcmPknG2NBc/Tl7ao9XOBwAJ) you have a good example of how works.