# Rundeck Conditional options variables

Tags: rundeck

I have a question about rundeck (noob alert !)

I need to set conditionnal options variables, (don't know if its the good word).

For exemple, i want to launch a job with only one value option:
*Customer01*

and i need to have a relation between variable.

If i put Customer01 the other variable need to dynamic have default options:
exemple:

*if
cust = Customer01ID
then ID = MyID and Oracle_schema = Myschema.
How can i make this working ?*

Thanks a lot and forgive me if my problem is not clear.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do that is using cascade options, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59292940/10426011) answer.

Another way is just scripting, basing on an [option](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/job-options.html#job-options) selection and using an [inline script](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/node-steps/builtin.html#script-step) step you can do anything based on the option selected, let me share a job definition based example (save as a YAML file and [import](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/creating-jobs.html#importing-job-definitions) to your instance to test it):

```yaml
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: e89a7cb0-2ecc-445d-b744-c1eebd540c91
  loglevel: INFO
  name: VariablesExample
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  options:
  - name: customer_id
    value: acme
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: null
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - fileExtension: .sh
      interpreterArgsQuoted: false
      script: |-
        database="none"

        if [ "@option.customer_id@" = "fiat" ]; then
        database="oracle"
        else
        database="postgresql"
        fi

        echo "setting $database"
      scriptInterpreter: /bin/bash
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: e89a7cb0-2ecc-445d-b744-c1eebd540c91
```

Basically, the script takes the option value (`@option.customer_id@`) and based on that option sets the bash variable `$database` and does anything.

So, probably you're thinking about executing a specific step based on a job option, and for that, you can use the [ruleset strategy](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/workflow-strategies/ruleset.html) (Rundeck Enterprise), which basically is a way to design complex workflows and a perfect scenario is to execute specific steps based on a job option selection.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.

I already check about the cascade option as json but i don't know how to build it 

Every page i loook seems to have only one value and no possible conditional options. exemple

[
    {"name":"windowsDesk", "value":"windsk.json"},
    {"name":"windowsSrv",  "value":"winsrv.json"}
]

And the script is an idea but if something change i need to change my script everytime